# Why does AWS Cloudformation say "Invalid request" when trying to create this RecordSetGroup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS CloudFormation file that includes this:

```
"myELB" : {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  Blah Blah Blah
},
"DatabaseDNSRecord" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "DependsOn": ["myELB"],
  "Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneId" : "Z19Y4P1DDQJADI", # obfuscated obviously.
    "RecordSets" : [
      {
        "Name" : "mydns.privatehostedzone.",
        "Type" : "CNAME",
        "ResourceRecords" : [
            {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["myELB","DNSName"]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

When I run it, I get the following cryptic error:

```
Error Message: 18:59:16 UTC-0500 CREATE_FAILED  AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup DatabaseDNSRecord Invalid request
```

Can someone suggest what the problem is here? I don't see what I'm doing wrong. `myELB` is successfully created.

Comment: What happens when you do "validate" on the template? Also, the particulars of the hosted zone might be relevant. e.g. what is the hosted zone name actually..

Comment: @AssafLavie, the name of my hosted zone is `privatehostedzone.`. When I attempt to validate it, the validator just sits there with no output whatsoever. It doesn't respond with an error or a verification message: `aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file:////My//path////mytemplatefile.json`. In fact when I replaced the template file with a file containing only `Hello world`, it behaved the same way. Very strange. But AWS lets me start building the stack with this file. If the file was syntactically incorrect, AWS would reject it outright.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas for what could be wrong in the template. I can only suggest that you "binary-search" through it until you get it to work: try a different resource type (A record, just point it to some random ip), try a different zone, try providing the cname record directly without Ref - narrow it down.. good luck!

Comment: Oh wait, this might be the unfortunate answer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=169745&tstart=0

Comment: Your code snippet didn't show that you were trying to create a private hosted zone in CFN. Yes, that's still not supported. But if you're just trying to add recordsets to an existing zone, that's certainly supported.

Comment: Yes Assaf. My last comment was not correct. Thanks.

Comment: Cloudformation now supports creating private hosted zones that can be associated with a VPC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone-hostedzonevpcs.html

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here. TTL is needed. Even though the [**docs**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html) wrongly state that it is not.

https://serverfault.com/questions/649004/aws-cloudformation-returning-invalid-request-when-trying-to-create-a-awsrout

Comment: Actually it is now.

`Required: Conditional. If you don't specify the AliasTarget property, you must specify this property. If you are creating an alias resource record set, do not specify this property.`

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with Cloudformation `"HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest"` error while creating other AWS resource (`AWS::KafkaConnect::Connector` which is far from being well documented as of today). One option to get more descriptive error is to go to CloudTrail and find exact Cloudformation event that has failed (you can use exact time range). In CloudTrail event json you will find `responseElements.message` that might bring more detail information. It has solve the problem for me, perhaps will be useful for others in future.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this question and trying to create a RecordSet with an AliasTarget. Providing a TTL will actually cause the same 'invalid request' failure.  e.g.

```
ApplicationDNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: <some-zone-id>
      Comment: DNS Entry for the Application Load balancer
      Name:  !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', '.domain.com.']]
      Type: A
      TTL: 60
      AliasTarget:
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
        HostedZoneId:  !GetAtt AppLoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneID
        DNSName: !GetAtt AppLoadBalancer.DNSName
    DependsOn:
      - AppLoadBalancer
```

In this situation providing the TTL actualy breaks the stack (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-ttl) It seems the TTL is specified on the target side.