# Aws CDK create sampling rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-xray

can someone point out the error in this instantiation? I tested this rule in the console and it seems to work:

```js
import * as xray from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-xray';
    
new xray.CfnSamplingRule(this, 'ignoreHttpOptionsSamplingRule', {
      ruleName: 'ignoreOptionsRequest',
      samplingRule: {
        fixedRate: 0,
        host: '*',
        httpMethod: 'OPTIONS',
        priority: 9999,
        reservoirSize: 0,
        resourceArn: '*',
        serviceName: '*',
        serviceType: '*',
        urlPath: '*',
        version: 1,
      },
    });
```

I get the following error

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: CreateSamplingRuleRequest(SamplingRule=SamplingRule(ResourceARN=*, Priority=9999, FixedRate=0.0, ReservoirSize=0, ServiceName=*, ServiceType=*, Host=*, HTTPMethod=OPTIONS, URLPath=*, Version=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890687/why-does-aws-cloudformation-say-invalid-request-when-trying-to-create-this-rec#:%7E:text=I%20was%20struggling%20with%20Cloudformation) about cloudtrail helped me find the issue. It seems like the rule name in props is deprecated and `ruleName` is supported inside sampling rule. the final code that worked was

```
    new xray.CfnSamplingRule(this, 'ignoreHttpOptionsSamplingRule', {
      samplingRule: {
        ruleName: 'ignore-options-request',
        httpMethod: 'OPTIONS',
        resourceArn: '*',
        serviceName: '*',
        serviceType: '*',
        urlPath: '*',
        host: '*',
        version: 1,
        fixedRate: 0,
        priority: 9999,
        reservoirSize: 0,
      },
    });
```